# Comparison between pointer and integer?

Tags: ios, warnings

How would I fix this warning in this if statement?

```
if ((NSUInt == nil) || (myInt == nil)) {
    NSUInt = 0;
    myInt = 0;
}
```

I get comparison between pointer and integer.

Thanks!

Edit: This seemed to fix it:

```
if ((!NSUInt) || (!myInt)) {
    NSUInt = 0;
    myInt = 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to properly tag your question with relevant tags.

Comment: there seems to be a terrible confusion of ideas going on in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try simple !myInt instead of myInt==nil and !NSUInt instead of == 0?

Comment: So this seemed to fix it: if ((!NSUInt) || (!myInt)) {
        NSUInt = 0;
        myInt = 0;
    }

Comment: if this solved your question please mark it :) happy it works (or at least it seems to work)

Answer (score 3):

Then don't compare pointers and integers:

```
myInt == 0
```

(I'm guessing that myInt is an integer, but I don't know what NSUInt is.)